# Stress concentration

Tags: materials, stresses, statics, solid-mechanics

Let's say we are using an aluminium with a yield and ultimate stress for an element like this:
[image]

In this case we will get some stress concentration around the fillet due to the change of area, however, because aluminium is a ductile material and assuming only static loading we could just ignore it (local yielding would occur and the stress wil be redistributed). Can we keep ignoring this stress concentration even if we get a higher value that the ultimate stress?

Comment: Depends on the curvature ( primarily "r" ) and the specific material. For example the proportions shown would still cause stress concentration for high strength steel ( eg 100.000 psi yield ).

Answer (score 1):

If you get local stress in the fillet higher than ultimate stress using linear elastic analysis, the part may still be ok. It is important that the average stress in the cross-section is less than the ultimate stress with some margin. Limiting factor may be how much the part needs to yield to get to the equilibrium and if the material has adequate elongation property.